# Making a striped rectangle in java with setColor

Tags: java, swing

I was busy practising for an exam I have in the upcoming days and I was wondering how I can make a rectangle switch between black and white example for example a traffic lights' pole. I currently have this:

```
for (streepjes = 0; streepjes < 8; streepjes++) {
     if (streepjes % 2 == 0) {
         tekening.setColor(Color.white);
         tekening.fillRect(43 + (100 * aantal) , 210 + (30 * streepjes), 25, 
                           275 + (30 * streepjes));
      }              
      tekening.setColor(Color.black);
      tekening.fillRect(43 + (100 * aantal) , 210 + (5 * streepjes), 25, 
                              275 + (5 * streepjes));
}
```

It seems that black is having a stronger working than the white and I have no idea how to fix this. Could someone please help me?

EDIT: Here is the whole code:

```
@Override
    public void init() {
        setSize(500,500);
    }

@Override
public void paint(Graphics tekening) {  

    int aantal;
            int streepjes;

    // Alles licht


    //Ik moet het zelfde vier keer maken
            for (aantal = 0; aantal < 4; aantal++) {

                // Eerst een zwart witte stok
                for (streepjes = 0; streepjes < 8; streepjes++) {
                    if (streepjes % 2 == 0) {
                        tekening.setColor(Color.white);
                        tekening.fillRect(43 + (100 * aantal) , 210 + (30 * streepjes), 25, 275 + (30 * streepjes));
                    }

                    tekening.setColor(Color.black);
                    tekening.fillRect(43 + (100 * aantal) , 210 + (5 * streepjes), 25, 275 + (5 * streepjes));
            }

                //Daarna het bord
                tekening.setColor(Color.black);
                tekening.fillRoundRect(20 + (100 * aantal), 10, 70, 220, 75, 75);

            }

    //Nu moeten we een groene, oranje en rode cirkel maken
            //Eerst de groene cirkel
    tekening.setColor(Color.green);
    tekening.fillOval(30, 30, 50, 50);

            //Nu de oranje cirkel
    tekening.setColor(Color.orange);
    tekening.fillOval(30, 95, 50, 50);

            //En tot slot de rode cirkel
    tekening.setColor(Color.red);
    tekening.fillOval(30, 160, 50, 50);


            //Nu het stoplicht met groen
    //De groene cirkel
    tekening.setColor(Color.green);
    tekening.fillOval(130, 30, 50, 50);

            //Nu rood en oranje die uitstaan
    tekening.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    tekening.fillOval(130, 95, 50, 50);
    tekening.fillOval(130, 160, 50, 50);


            //Vervolgens het stoplicht met oranje
    //Eerst de oranje cirkel
    tekening.setColor(Color.orange);
    tekening.fillOval(230, 95, 50, 50);

            //Daarna groen en rood die uit staan
    tekening.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    tekening.fillOval(230, 160, 50, 50);
    tekening.fillOval(230, 30, 50, 50);


    //En als laatst het stoplicht met rood
            //Eerst de rode cirkel
    tekening.setColor(Color.red);
    tekening.fillOval(330, 160, 50, 50);

            //Daarna groen en oranje die uitstaan
    tekening.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    tekening.fillOval(330, 30, 50, 50);
    tekening.fillOval(330, 95, 50, 50);
}
```

}

Comment: This looks like it is Swing, perhaps add the Swing tag.

Comment: Would you mind adding a complete, run-able example? I currently cannot figure out what the variable _aantal_ is used for. The other thing I'm a bit curious about is that you are dynamically changing the height of your rectangles. I cannot get an idea of what you are expecting to get drawn?

Comment: Well you paint the black every time through your loop, so I would guess it is overwriting the white painting which is only done every second time.